Do "always prepared" Spells cost spell slots?
In 2024 D&D, Druids "always have the Speak with Animals spell prepared."
I think that this means only that Speak with Animals doesn't count as one of the "Prepared Spells" (e.g., 4 at level 1), but I want to be sure that it doesn't also mean that Speak with Animals is effectively a cantrip (i.e., castable at will).
Do folks agree that a level-1+ spell that is "always prepared" still requires a spell slot to cast?

Casting the "always prepared" Speak With Animals requires expending a slot (unless otherwise specified)
Unlike some classes, Druids prepare their daily spells. Druids prepare (most of) their spells after a long rest.

You prepare the list of level 1+ spells that are available for you to cast...

But, sometimes they get spells that are "always prepared".

Certain features might give you a spell that you always have prepared. If you also have a list of prepared spells that you can change, a spell that you always have prepared doesn’t count against the number of spells on that list.

Having a particular spell "always prepared" means that they don't have to pay any opportunity cost for choosing it, over another spell, to prepare for the day. Otherwise, prepared spells follow normal Druid spell casting rules.

When you cast a spell, you expend a slot of that spell’s level or higher

Speak With Animals is a level 1 spell, which means (unless otherwise specified) a spell slot must be expended in order to cast it.

Terminology note: in D&D 2024, all classes "prepare" their spells.  Some classes only get to add or change on level-up, but they still call that "preparing" (e.g. Bard in the Free Rules 2024 on dnd beyond).  (This hopefully avoids problems or confusion with wording in things like feats that give you spells where 5e-2014 had some classes with spells known vs. some with prepared.) So you could say "Unlike some classes, druids prepare their spells daily".  (as opposed to on level-up).

Yes, but not always
I agree with nonymous's answer, but I think it's worth noting that certain traits from your species, features from your class, or feats can give you prepared spells that you can cast without using a spell slot—typically through the Short or Long Rest mechanic:

Special Feature. Some features are recharged by a Short Rest. If you
have such a feature, it recharges in the way specified in its
description.


Special Feature. Some features are recharged by a Long Rest. If you
have such a feature, it recharges in the way specified in its
description.

For example (emphases mine):

The Elven Lineage trait from elves:


When you reach character levels 3 and 5, you learn a higher-level
spell, as shown on the table. You always have that spell prepared.
You can cast it once without a spell slot, and you regain the
ability to cast it in that way when you finish a Long Rest. You can
also cast the spell using any spell slots you have of the appropriate
level.


The Ranger and its Favored Enemy feature:


You always have the Hunter's Mark spell prepared. You can cast it
twice without expending a spell slot, and you regain all expended uses
of this ability when you finish a Long Rest.


The Magic Initiate feat:


Level 1 Spell. Choose a level 1 spell from the same list you selected
for this feat's cantrips. You always have that spell prepared. You can
cast it once without a spell slot, and you regain the ability to cast
it in that way when you finish a Long Rest. You can also cast the
spell using any spell slots you have.

